# Formview in UpdatePanel is not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel with a Repeater inside a Panel. By clicking in one of the cells of the repeater, 2 detailed Views (Gridview, Formview - each one in a UpdatePanel) are displayed based on the repeater's argument passed in a LinkButton.

While the Gridview is displaying fine, the FormView is not when Updating their UpdatePanels. All the DataBindings should be working correctly as I had been running the app for a year - but without the UpdatePanels! I am using them for the first time and must be missing something.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>                                          
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Height="600px">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="RepeaterKalendar">
            <ItemTemplate>  
                ...
                <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonSelect" runat="server" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("date") %>' Text='<%# Bind("TAG") %>' OnClick="GetDetails"/>
                ...
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_Grid" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="Server">
<ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Grid_Details" OnSelectedIndexChanged="IndexChanged">
    ...
    </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel_Form" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="Form_Details" DefaultMode="Edit"">
        <EditItemTemplate>
        ...
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind for LinkButton Click

```
protected void GetDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton LinkButton1 = (sender as LinkButton);
    string commandArgument = LinkButton1.CommandArgument;
    BuildDetailsViewReport(Convert.ToDateTime(commandArgument));
    BuildDetailsViewList(Convert.ToDateTime(commandArgument));
    UpdatePanel_Grid.Update();
    UpdatePanel_Form.Update();             
}
```

UpdatePanel_Form.Update() does not update the FormView and causes even that the GridView is not updated. If I remove that command from the code, the GridView is uploaded correctly.

Any help is appreciated.
Martin

Comment: I rebuild this scenario from scratch with just the 3 elements (repeater, gridview, formview) in their UpdatePanels... and it works. Don't have a clue why it's not working in my finished solution with over 200KB. Although this is going to be painful, at least I know that it is supposed to work I thought

Comment: You might have to set the form back to normal view mode, update, then set it to edit mode again. (?)